# How do I specify the version of Thin web server I want to use for my Ruby app? - Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, thin

I have the following versions installed:

```
 thin (1.2.11, 1.2.7, 1.2.2)
```

But I always want to use version `1.2.2`

How do I specify?

Am using Sinatra.

This is how I run my site:

`ruby app/website/website.rb`

I eventually want to be able to explictly use Thin like this:

`thin start -R apps/website/website.ru -d` so how would I specify the version of `Thin` to be used there also?

When I run the first command, I see this:

```
== Sinatra/0.9.2 has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from Thin
>> Thin web server (v1.2.11 codename Bat-Shit Crazy)
```

So I know it's not using the correct version `1.2.2`.

Comment: Curious, but why do you want to use 1.2.2 and not the latest version?

Comment: The site I am working on is finicky and demands the exact version number of the gems in order to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Calling the Sinatra app directly

When running a Sinatra app directly (e.g. with `ruby app/website/website.rb`), to specify which web server to use as the built-in server, you use the [`:server` configuration option](http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html#__handler_used_for_builtin_web_server) (Thin will be used by default if it is installed):

```
set :server, :thin
```

To specify the particular version to use, you need to control which gem is loaded. The best way to do this is probably using [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/) with a `Gemfile`, and then call `require 'bunlder/setup'` early on in your app.

If you're not using Bundler, you can specify which version of a gem to load with the `gem` method in your app:

```
gem 'thin', '1.2.2'
```

(do this *after* `require`ing rubygems if you're using Ruby 1.8.7 or earlier).

## Starting with `thin start`

If you're calling `thin` directly with a `config.ru` file, then you can specify the version you want on the command line:

```
thin _1.2.2_ start -R config.ru
```

(this is the same for any gem binary: use `_x_` as the first argument, and version `x` will be used)

In this case I think you need to explicitly use the `-R` option - it looks like Thin doesn't automatically find the `config.ru` file like it does when simply using `thin start`.

If you have specified which version to use in your app file, you need to make sure you specify the same version on the command line, otherwise you'll get errors like `can't activate thin-1.2.2, already activated thin-1.2.11 (Gem::LoadError)`.

If you decide to use Bundler, then calling `bundle exec thin start` will use the versions in your `Gemfile`.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Bundler, you can specify the version in your Gemfile, then use `bundle exec thin ...` to start your server. You can also use the full path to the appropriate gem executable (which you can obtain using `bundle show <gemname>`).

If you don't have Bundler, you can use `gem which <gemname>`.

Whichever you use, you can execute thin like this (pretty hacky though):

```
$ `bundle show thin`/bin/thin start
```

or:

```
$ `gem which thin`/../../bin/thin start
```

I think you could also use Bash substitutions, or you can hardcode the path.

Comment: Not using bundler...but when I run `gem show` I get this error: `gem show thin
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (RuntimeError)
    Unknown command show`

Thoughts?

Comment: Right, sorry. It's `bundle show`... but you don't have Bundler. (Why not?)

Comment: Ok @Nexerus that worked. Now how do I specify this exact version of Thin to be used now?

Comment: @FélixSaparelli the site I am working on, doesn't use it. Have to stick with what's there.

Comment: That doesn't work to run. This is what happens: `$ bundle show thin /Users/marcamillion/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/thin.rb ruby app/website/website.rb
"show" was called incorrectly. Call as "bundle show [GEM]".`

Thoughts?

Comment: Even if I do this: `$ bundle show thin /Users/marcamillion/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/thin.rb start
"show" was called incorrectly. Call as "bundle show [GEM]".`